# american accent tool or website

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, accent, american-accent

I am a non native speaker.

I have never talked English with anyone before. so all my accent depends only on how I see the word or if I heard it from a movie.

Is there any website or tool **FREE** that I can give it a word and it will say it in an American accent? I know it couldn't be 100% accurate but it is helpful to me.

Comment: Try this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

Comment: you can use forvo, where native speakers pronounce phrases and words, you can chose what accent do you want: https://forvo.com/

Comment: google translator uses a digital voice that's nowadays almost perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many internet dictionaries provide recorded pronunciations: [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/), [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english), [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aMain_Page), and others.

On some of these British and US pronunciations appear on the same page, on others you must be careful to select the 'U.S. English' version in your search.

Keep in mind, however, that the 'American accent' varies widely: Southerners, New Englanders, New Yorkers, Midwesterners, Minnesotans have markedly different pronunciations of some words; and no two people say anything exactly the same way. (In fact no **one** person says anything the same way consistently.)

Comment: I am trying the oxfor webiste, there is no option for choosing the american accent. I tried "center" and it pronouced the "T" and it is not an american accent. I will keep trying your other links

Comment: in the oxfox there is `"US"` sign, is that american or england please?

Comment: 'US' is 'American'. It's short for 'USA', which means 'the United States of America'.  (That's a basic answer - it's actually more complicated than that.)

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli At ODO you must select from the dropdown menu at the ▼ on the left of the search box. I'm not sure what you mean by 'pronounced the "T"'; we do not universally or invariably pronounce the word /sɛnr/, particularly not when it is stressed or isolated - see my last paragraph.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english/1057#1057). (Stoney, I hope you don't mind me quoting the first part of your answer here in the Resources meta thread.) And +1 here for your last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

My choice is [IVONA TTS](http://www.ivona.com/us/). It is amazing. [It has a free app for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts.voicebeta.eng.usa.kendra). I use it to listen to the new words and their example sentences that I have listed and also to listen to the interesting news and texts to improve my listening skills.  I use it in combination with ["Voice reading"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noinnion.android.voicereading) app.

Comment: I've added this information to the [ELL Resources thread](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735), under the entry for [Pronunciation](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english/1057#1057).

Comment: @J.R. see.... this time I asked a good question B-)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see much sense in such applications. I believe that an English-speaking environment with the right accent simplifies the training of your pronunciation in several times. To get a good accent, you need to train a lot, read various articles and tutorials about [american accent training](https://accenthero.com/american-accent-training) and of course you need to watch a lot of american movies and TV shows. You can look at udemi some courses, it could cost you a couple of bucks